# Spring 3 MVC extra @RequestMapping value getting appended to returned view

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-3

I have a view `'hi.jsp`' with user name and password text fields. I need to submit `'hi.jsp'` to `'LoginController.java'`. If there is any error in the data submitted then `'LoginController.java'` must redirect the request back to `'hi.jsp'` (with text fields retaning the entered data) with respective error messages. After changing data and re-submitting `'hi.jsp'` I get 404 error.

So the first submission is successful however problem occurs during second submission.
The source code of files is mentioned below:

**hi.jsp**

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
  <%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="s" %>
  <%@ page session="false" %>
  <html>
      <body>    
        <s:form method="POST" modelAttribute="loginObj" action="login/validatelogin">
           <label for="userName">UserName</label>
           <s:input path="userName" id="userName" size="15"/><br>
           <div style="{color:red}"> <s:errors path="userName"></s:errors></div>

           <label for="password">Password</label>
           <s:input path="password" id="password" size="15" /><br>
           <s:errors path="password"></s:errors>

           <input name="submit" type="submit" value="login"/>      
    </s:form>
   </body>
</html>
```

**LoginController.java**

```
package rajeev.spring.spitter.mvc.controller;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/login")
public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/validatelogin", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String validateLogin(@Valid @ModelAttribute("loginObj") LoginBean loginObj, BindingResult bindingResult)
    {
        System.out.println(bindingResult.hasErrors());
        if(bindingResult.hasErrors())
        {
            return "hi";
        }
        return "home";
    }
}
```

**spitter-servlet.xml (spring configuration)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="rajeev.spring.spitter.mvc.controller"></context:component-scan>
     <bean  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
  </bean>
</beans>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>Spring Hello World</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>springDispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
      <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spitter-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>springDispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

During the second submission of 'hi.jsp' tomcat log also displays a warning:

```
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringMVC/login/login/validatelogin] in DispatcherServlet with name 'springDispatcher'
```

It seems that during second submission of `'hi.jsp`' an extra `'/login'` is getting appended to the submission path of the form.

Kindly suggest if something is wrong with above code or do I need to modify it to make it working.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the relative form post URL changed when you map your handler method into a different URL

```
<s:form method="POST" modelAttribute="loginObj" action="login/validatelogin">
```

Common solution to this problem is to use absolute path, but instead of hardcoding, lookup your context-path using

```
<c:set var="root" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}"/>
```

Then on your form

```
<s:form method="POST" modelAttribute="loginObj" action="${root}/login/validatelogin">
```

Other option you might consider is to use Post-Redirect pattern in your controller handler method to avoid switching the URL

```
public String validateLogin(@Valid @ModelAttribute("loginObj") LoginBean loginObj, BindingResult bindingResult) {
  ....
  return "redirect:/login";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<c:url var="myAction" value="/login/validatelogin"/>
<s:form method="POST" modelAttribute="loginObj" action="${myAction}">
```

Comment: This is not preferrable since the leading slash might wipe off the context-root. Eg if the app is installed with context-root myapp: http://myhost/myapp, the form will post to http://myhost/login/validatelogin instead of http://myhost/myapp/login/validatelogin